# May I know why the counter is 1 and 4 for this code?

Tags: c

I am given sort(a,4),sort(a,6) in this question.

```
Starting with sort(a,4)
npts =4 which mean I need to loop from 0 ~ 2
1st loop x[] = { 5,7,3,1,6,9}
2nd loop x[] = {5,3,7,1,6,9}
3rd loop x[] = {5,3,1,7,6,9}
exit the loop
counter =1;
back into the for loop
1st loop x[] = {3,5,1,7,6,9}
2nd loop x[] = {3,1,5,7,6,9}
exit loop the loop
counter =2;
back into the for loop
1st loop x[] = {1,3,5,7,6,9}
exit the loop
counter =3;
back into the for loop
but exit immediately since 1>3 
counter = 4;

Then going to the sort(a,6);
counter =1 since 1>3;

But the answer is opposite when I compile using mingw which is 1 4
```

My code is as followed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sort (int x[],int npts);
int main(void)
{       
   int a[] = {7,5,3,1,6,9};
    printf("%d %d\n",sort(a,4),sort(a,6)); 
       return 0;
    }
    int sort(int x[] , int npts)
    {
       int counter =0, done, hold ,k;

       do
        {

          done =1;
          for(k=0;k<=npts-2;k++)
          {
             if (x[k] > x[k+1])
             {       

                hold= x[k];
                x[k] = x[k+1];
                x[k+1] = hold;
                done =0;  
              }
          }
          counter++;
        }while (!done);
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: `printf` split to `printf("%d ",sort(a,4));printf("%d\n", sort(a,6));`  this will specify the order in which the function is called

Answer (score 5):

```
 Starting with sort(a,4) npts =4 ...
```

No. It doesn't have to be. You seem to be expecting `sort(a,4)` called first and then `sort,6)`. The order of evaluation of arguments to printf() function is *unspecified*. That means, you don't know which one of `sort(1,4` and `sort(a,6)` will be called first.

Calling them one after another would give predictable result.